# fill dataset without loss the previous data

Tags: c#

I try to design a report using report viewer

I have TableAdapter that will fill the dataset and it take one parameter which is ID

what I want to do is fill the dataset by pass different ID inside while loop and at each loop 
add new data to dataset . .

my problem now is when I add new data the previous data will loss ..

```
int i = 0 ;
while (i <= 2)
{
    this.con_detailsTableAdapter.FillBycust_no(this.majiddbDataSet.con_details, i.ToString());
    i += 1; 
}

this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly there is a property in  `TableAdapter` called `ClearBeforeFill`.

Set it to `false` and it will not be cleared first.